# How can i "merge" rows which are having identical values using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns i.e. name and respective message.

I am trying to figure out how I can merge rows that have identical name values (like in the photo below) without impacting 2nd column.

Table view

[image]

Expectation is to extract the table in the form of clusters and respective count of message occurrences from column 2, PFB

Table expected

[image]

How to perform this action using Pandas in Python?

Comment: Instead of posting df image can you use `df.to_dict()` and paste the `dict` here?

Comment: If I understand you corectly, you would want one row for User B that containts a concatinated string "Hi How are you". Is that correct?

Comment: Please post the original dataset (or a sample of the original dataset) that is used to generate the dataframe. And also, please show your code.

Comment: let's take your dataset:
    `df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"User_name" : ["User A", "User B", "User B", "User C", "User A", "User C", "User C", "User C", "User C"], "Text": ["Hello", "Hi", "How are you", "Yes", "Oka", "Hi", "How are you", "Hi", "How are you"]})`  

To get close to what you are trying:  
`(df.groupby("User_name").Text.value_counts().reset_index(name="count"))`  
I don't think it's possible to do the partly grouped rows.

Comment: correction:
`df.groupby("User_name").Text.value_counts().reset_index(name="count")`
I have trouble with the formatting here :)

Comment: Yeah, so basically i can't break the continuity of the communication. Hence using groupby will merge all the identical row values into 1 row.. I want in the form of cluster.